# Google Script update cells based on new inputs

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using Google Scripts with the aim of calling an already filled cell using the ID. Once the data has been called, the user would be able to update and send it back to the main "data", in case some update is necessary.

The code isn't giving any error, but is not updating the cells either. See below an example of the code:

```
function Update() {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formS = ss.getSheetByName("App"); // From sheet 
  var dataS = ss.getSheetByName("Results"); // Get the data already inputted

  var str = formS.getRange("D6").getValue(); // The ID to find and to update in the "Inputs" sheet
  var values = dataS.getDataRange().getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i<=values.length; i++) {
    var rowFinder = values[i];
    if (rowFinder[columnIndex] == str) {
      var rowNumber = i+1;
      var updatedValues = [[formS.getRange("D9").getValue(),
        formS.getRange("D13").getValue(),
        formS.getRange("D14").getValue(),
        formS.getRange("D15").getValue(),
        formS.getRange("D16").getValue(),
        formS.getRange("D17").getValue(),
        formS.getRange("D18").getValue(),
        formS.getRange("D19").getValue()]];
      
      dataS.getRange(rowNumber, 2, 1, 17).setValues(updatedValues);
    }
  break;
  }
}
```

Find also an example of the sheet that I'm using, where you could also see the whole code (everything else is working fine). Spreadhsheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11zlovigfElj1q8JQslIMJQ9SeU-o-v41wmpNCtz3JCY/edit?usp=sharing)

Why function is not updating the data? I've tried to put the `dataS.getRange(rowNumber, 2, 1, 17).setValues(updatedValues);` in different parts of the code and it doesn't work either. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is best to get the values of a range all at once and iterate through the entire range than pulling individual cells.

I tested this on your sample spreadsheet (Thanks for including!)

```
function SubmitData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formS = ss.getSheetByName("App"); // Add the name of the sheet where the data is going to be retrieved
  var dataS = ss.getSheetByName("Results"); // Name of the sheet where the data should appear

  //get the entire form range
  var values = formS.getRange(6, 3, 14, 2).getValues();
  
  //Create an array to paste into the Results tab
  var pasteArr =[];
  
  //iterate through the two columns on the App tab, only add values to the paste array
  //if Col C is not blank and does not equal "Choose Params" 
  for (var i in values) {
     //the values array looks like this [[row1Col1, row1Col2],[row2Col1, row2Col2]..]
     //so to get to the value in row i, column 1 you use values[i][0]       
    let field = values[i][0];
    
    if (field != "" && field != "Choose Params") {
      let val = values[i][1];
      pasteArr.push(val);
    }
  };

  Logger.log(pasteArr);
  var dataLastRow = dataS.getLastRow() + 1;
  
  //Build the range to paste in - use the length of pasteArr to get the proper number of columns
  //then to make pasteArr a 2D array put pasteArr inside another array by using square brackets
  dataS.getRange(dataLastRow, 1, 1, pasteArr.length).setValues([pasteArr]);
  Logger.log("Done");
  
  ClearCell();
}
```

Your other functions have similar issues.

```
function Update() {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formS = ss.getSheetByName("App"); // From sheet 
  var dataS = ss.getSheetByName("Results"); // Get the data already inputted
  var dataVals = dataS.getDataRange().getValues();
  
  //get the entire form range 
  var values = formS.getRange(6, 3, 14, 2).getValues();
  
  //Create an array to paste into the Results tab
  var pasteArr =[];
  
  //iterate through the two columns on the App tab, only add values to the paste array
  //if Col C is not blank and does not equal "Choose Params" 
  for (var i in values) {
    let field = values[i][0];
    
    if (field != "" && field != "Choose Params") {
      let val = values[i][1];
      pasteArr.push(val);
    }
  }
  
  let numCols = pasteArr.length;
  
  //iterate through the rows on the data tab, update the row with the matching ID
  for (var j in dataVals) {
    let dataTableId = dataVals[j][0];
    let formID = pasteArr[0];

    Logger.log(dataTableId + " , "+formID);
    
    if (dataTableId === formID){
      //have to convert j from 0 index to columns by adding 1.  The + before the j and the 1 force app script to treat it as a number.
      dataS.getRange(+j+ +1, 1, 1, numCols).setValues([pasteArr]);
      Logger.log("dataTableId matches");
    }
  }
  Logger.log("Done");
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response Krispin! Yet, one thing that I've noticed is that, instead of changing the row with the ID to edit, for example, ID 2, it appends all the information in another row. How can I make that this changes are applied in the same row as the ID requested?

Comment: Yes, sorry I did the Submit function by accident, I am updating my answer with the Update function in addition.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Krispin! Now it works perfectly! I will take a look at the Clear function in order to improve it. Totally grateful!